# Integral of an indicator function

Tags: integration

Just wanted to ask for a quick verification of the following:

Let $\mathbf{1}_{(0,x]}$ be an indicator function. Then

$\int_0^\infty\mathbf{1}_{(0,x]}^2(t)dt=\int_0^\infty\mathbf{1}_{(0,x]}(t)dt=\int_0^xdt=x$.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Great,thank you.